# Search among the documents the user has permission to read in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a collection of documents. Each document has child `uid` which is a reference to the owner. Exemplary document:

```
{
  "uid": "slfjs092320i3jf023jf",
  "content": "Example"
}
```

I want to store them under `/documents` collection and allow only users with matching uid to store and retrieve them. I created the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "documents": {
      "$documentId": {
        ".read": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid",
        ".write": "newData.exists() && newData.child('uid').val() === auth.uid || data.exists() && data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid",
        ".indexOn": ["uid"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunatelly when I want to retrieve user's documents I receive permission denied. To retrieve documents I use:

```
export default getUserDocuments = () => {
    const userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase.database()
        .ref('/documents')
        .orderByChild('uid')
        .equalTo(userUid)
        .once('value');
};
```

How do I query user's documents? I guess the permission denied is related to read restriction required to perform the query.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Database enforced read permission when you attach a listener. To be able to read from `/documents`, you will need to have read permission on `/documents`. Since that isn't the case with your security rules, the listener is rejected.

This may be counter-intuitive initially, and means that security rules cannot be used to filter data in the way you are trying. This is known as [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) in the documentation, and has been the topic of [many previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters). I recommend you check out some of those, and report back if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
What would be the good way to store this data? Suppose my documents also have category. Should I create two collections? One named `usersDocuments` with structure

{
  $uid: {
    content: "example"
  }
}

, and the second  `documentsWithCategories` with structure 
{
  $category: {
    document1tId: true, document2Id: true
  }
}
?

Comment: Typically you'll end up with a top-level list for each use-case that can't be met by your current structure. Those lists can either be full/partial duplicates, or just manual indexes (like in your your comment).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [query based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules).

Rules are not filters, as Frank said, and he is right, but you can make **some queries** to works and achieve something similar to what you were looking for with this kind of stuff :

```
baskets": {
  ".read": "auth.uid != null &&
            query.orderByChild == 'owner' &&
            query.equalTo == auth.uid" // restrict basket access to owner of basket
}
```

And then, this will work :

```
db.ref("baskets").orderByChild("owner")
                 .equalTo(auth.currentUser.uid)
                 .on("value", cb)
```

And this, won't :

```
db.ref("baskets").on("value", cb)
```